# How to overcome javascript problems?

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript, most of the stuffs are working only by javascript.
Sometimes the javascript functions are not called properly.

Can someone give fair idea about how to use use javascript,where to use javascript,what situation we need to use javascript etc...

One Scenario:-

```
$("#dialog").bgiframe({src:"about:blank"});
        CreateExternalLinks();
        if(jsonData._items.length>0)
            FillData(jsonData);
        HideDIV();
        HandleRating();
        //FindDefaultSearch();    
        SetPageStyle();    
        //HandleDefaultVideo();    
        HideInvite();    
        DialogAction("close");    
        SetSearchBoxTitle();    
        LoadWaitingDialog();    
        SetStyleForNewVideos();    
        $("div.home-video-rating").live("mouseout",function(){
            SetRating($currentRate);
         });
        SetPaging();
        if($("#divTitle").html().length==0)
        FindDefaultVideo();
}
```

These are functions that should call once the page is loaded on the client side.

Sometimes LoadWaitingDialog() is not called. I don't know the reason?

Comment: Use a debugging tool to inspect the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) extension for FireFox and check the console for exceptions.

It also has a handy feature under the script tab called "Break on All Errors" which will break into the code whenever an exception occurs, allowing you to inspect the state of local variables and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean...

```
$("#dialog").bgiframe({src:"about:blank"}, function () {
        CreateExternalLinks();
        if(jsonData._items.length>0)
            FillData(jsonData);
        HideDIV();
        HandleRating();
        //FindDefaultSearch();    
        SetPageStyle();    
        //HandleDefaultVideo();    
        HideInvite();    
        DialogAction("close");    
        SetSearchBoxTitle();    
        LoadWaitingDialog();    
        SetStyleForNewVideos();    
        $("div.home-video-rating").live("mouseout",function(){
            SetRating($currentRate);
         });
        SetPaging();
        if($("#divTitle").html().length==0)
        FindDefaultVideo();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)! It prevents you and warns you from syntax error and the wrong usage of JavaScript. If you have Firebug and YSlqow installed, than you can run JSLint in your Browser on the current page. Just open Firebug > YSlow > Tools > JSLint.